# How to calculate the mean value of multiple large rasters in python/arcpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raster, arcpy

After having converted the original monthly [MOD13C2](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod13c2v006/) product (from year 2000-2020) to *raster* format, now I have to calculate the **mean** value of the **251** rasters.

First I have tried this [tutorial](https://blog.csdn.net/lucky51222/article/details/109412616) which simply used the algebra function that behaved badly in cooperating NA values. So I tried the [second one](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_35056050/article/details/112017543) which converted each raster to array to skip NA pixel. I adapted it into my code:

```
import arcpy, sys, os, glob
from arcpy.sa import *
import numpy

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

# input path
inws = "G:/data0610/MODIS_VI/EVI/EVI_pro/"

# output path
outws = "G:/data0610/MODIS_VI/EVI/EVI_pro/"

rasters = glob.glob(os.path.join(inws, "*.tif"))

r = Raster(rasters[0])  
array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(r)  # convert to numpy
rowNum, colNum = array.shape  

sum = numpy.zeros(shape=array.shape)    # save the accumulating value
count = numpy.zeros(shape=array.shape)  # save the counting number
Average = numpy.zeros(shape=array.shape)    # save the mean value

for ras in rasters:
    rmm = Raster(ras)  
    array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rmm) 

    # one by one pixel
    for i in range(0, rowNum):
        for j in range(0, colNum):
            if array[i][j] >= 0 :  # verdict invalid value
                sum[i][j] += array[i][j]  # accumulate
                count[i][j] += 1    # counter
                continue

Average = sum / count   # cal the mean value

# save the raster
lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(r.extent.XMin, r.extent.YMin)  
cellWidth = r.meanCellWidth  
cellHeight = r.meanCellHeight

nameT = "evi.tif"
outname = os.path.join(outws, nameT)  

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True   

#convert to WGS84
inf = "G:/data0610/MODIS_VI/sm_mean.tif"
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = Raster(inf)   # convert the crs to wgs84
print("successfully converted the CRS!")

AvgRas = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(Average, lowerLeft, cellWidth, cellHeight, r.noDataValue)  # turn into raster
AvgRas.save(outname)
print("successfully output the evi_mean.tif!")

# resample
outname_res = outws + "evi_mean_res.tif"
# get the standard cellsize
cellsize025 = "{0} {1}".format(arcpy.Describe(inf).meanCellWidth, arcpy.Describe(inf).meanCellHeight)
arcpy.Resample_management(AvgRas, outname_res, cellsize025, "NEAREST")

print("successfully output the evi_mean.tif with the 0.25 degree resolution!")
```

Unfortunately, the arcpy (python 2.7, 32 bit) had the memory error because there were too many large rasters (I'm dealing with the global extent). I found the reason and solution from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291948/numpy-memory-error-on-large-rasters):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK8nP.png)

So I installed the 64-bit Background Geoprocessing of ArcGIS and run the above code again, then it came up with another problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bAS0.png)

It turned out the soultion might be useless, because ArcGIS is very sensitive to administrator license, you can't run the 64-bit python while the ArcGIS being 32-bit.

Now return to my initial question: How to calculate the mean value of multiple rasters in python/arcpy? Did I make things complicated? Is there a simpler way of generating the mean value raster?

It's really driving me crazy.

Comment: Please do not use such loops. Python is mainly interpreted via CPython which is known to be very slow for that. Consider using Numpy (vectorized) functions for that instead (eg. `np.sum` and `np.where` as weel as boolean expression). See the well-written tutorial for more information (in the doc). Also note that Python 2.7 is completely obsolete since few years and not maintained anymore (even security updates). It is deprecated since 14 years. Please switch to Python 3 (and if this is not possible please send a message to modules developers that did not make the switch yet -- for a decade).

Comment: @Jérôme Richard， thanks for your hlepful instructions of python coding, I'm gonna check out for the mentioned Numpy functions. But the reason why I'm using such a loop is to get rid of the null value of any raster, I couldn't fighure out a better way to do that with python. Anyway, THANKS for your help!

Comment: I found a way to deal with this problem eventually, that is to use matlab instead of arcpy, cause the former has an excellent function, nanmean.

Comment: Numpy also have an `np.nanmean` functions.